# AWS Lex built-in slots such as DayOfWeek or Food. How do they work?

Tags: amazon-web-services, built-in, amazon-lex, slots

I created a basic bot in the console using the AWS Lex built-in slots DayOfWeek and Food. However, they allow any input, e.g. "asdfasdfsdaf" to fill the slot. If the slots are not restricting the inputs to specific values then I don't understand the reason to use them? Or how to use them properly?

Thanks,
John

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50989732/aws-lex-default-slot-type-has-no-limits/51027385#51027385

Comment: Yes, that answers my question, thanks!